# Triangular Square insight

Tags: number-theory, problem-solving

I'm trying to find 
*Triangular numbers that are also square*. So $m^2=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$
I don't want the actual answer with the solution but I'd like to 
solve the problem myself : I need some clues to take me on the right track.

Comment: Are you familiar with Pell's equation and methods of solving equations of that form? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell's_equation

Comment: No. But now I can learn  Pell's equation.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76040/general-formula-to-obtain-triangular-square-numbers) also offers a great triangular-square insight.