# How would you do this question?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

"The first two numbers that are both squares and triangles are 1 and 36. Find the next one and, if possible, the one after that. Can you figure out an efficient way to find triangular–square numbers? Do you think that there are infinitely many?"

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know the formula for the triangular numbers?  Set it equal to $k^2$.  Note that I added the diophantine equations tag.  A spreadsheet will find the next couple easily.  Just compute the triangular numbers, take the square root, and search by eye for an integer.  I don't think that will help the general case.

Comment: I would do it by trying...

Comment: Can you find a less informative title?

Comment: @AndreasBlass It could have been the ever-so-popular "I have a math question."

Comment: Google search for "square triangular number"?

Comment: [Let me google it for you](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareTriangularNumber.html)

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76040/general-formula-to-obtain-triangular-square-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$${t_n} = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n k  = 1 + 2 + 3 +  \cdots  + n = \frac{{n\left( {n + 1} \right)}}{2} = n-th{\text{ triangular number}}$$
$${s_m} = {\text{m-th square number}} = {m^2}$$
$${s_m} = {t_n} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}n\left( {n + 1} \right) = {m^2}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}{\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)^2} = \frac{1}{2}\left( {{n^2} + n + \frac{1}{4}} \right) = \frac{1}{2}\left( {{n^2} + n} \right) + \frac{1}{8}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}n\left( {n + 1} \right) = \frac{1}{2}\left( {{n^2} + n} \right) = \frac{1}{2}{\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)^2} - \frac{1}{8} = {m^2}$$
$$\frac{1}{2}{\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)^2} - {m^2} = \frac{1}{8}$$
$$4{\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)^2} - 8{m^2} = 1$$
$$2 \cdot \left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right) \cdot 2\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right) - 8{m^2} = 1$$
$${\left( {2n + 1} \right)^2} - 8{m^2} = 1$$
$${\left( {2n + 1} \right)^2} - 2 \cdot {\left( {2m} \right)^2} = 1$$
$$\boxed{w \equiv 2n + 1}$$
$$\boxed{z \equiv 2m}$$
$$\boxed{{w^2} - 2{z^2} = 1}$$

Finding numbers that satisfy the last equation above isn't all that simple... so I found the first numbers that are both triangular and square using python

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
triangular_and_square = []
for n in np.arange(1,10000):
    w = 2*n + 1
    for m in np.arange(1,10000):
        z = 2*m
        if w*w - 2*z*z - 1 == 0:
            triangular_and_square.append([m*m,m,n])
output_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(triangular_and_square,
                                 columns = ["Square (m-squared) + Triangular","m","n"], 
                                 index = [1,2,3,4,5,6])

print(output_dataframe)
```

[Code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3uTW.png)

$$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
& {{\rm{Square (}}{m^2}){\rm{ and Triangular}}}&& m&& n& \\
\hline
& 1&& 1&& 1& \\
& {36}&& 6&& 8& \\
& {1225}&& {35}&& {49}& \\
& {41616}&& {204}&& {288}& \\
& {1413721}&& {1189}&& {1681}& \\
& {48024900}&& {6930}&& {9800}& 
\end{array}$$

Comment: Your code has both `triangular_and_square` and `triangluar_and_square`. Please could you check it for typos and make sure it is what you intend?

Comment: Oh wow. Didn't even notice I did that.
triangluar_and_square = []  <---- a list
triangluar_and_square.append([m*m,m,n]) <--- adding values to the list
triangular_and_square <---- a dataframe
triangular_and_square = pd.DataFrame(triangluar_and_square.... <---- I used the list _triangluar_and_square to create the dataframe triangular_and_square.

I should've used different names for the dataframe and the list. The old version worked fine., but I changed the name of the dataframe to avoid confusion. Sorry about my sloppy original answer.