# Triangle and square number

Tags: square-numbers, pattern-recognition

Triangle numbers are  $0,1,3,6,10...$ 
And square numbers are $0,1,4,9,16...$ 
$N$'th triangle no. = $N(N+1)/2$
$N$'th square no. = $N\cdot N$

So I was wondering are there any numbers which are in both these lists apart from $0,1$??

I found one using trial and error that is $36$ which is the $8$'th triangular number and $6$'th square number. Are there more? What is the algebraic method to calculate them?? thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_triangular_number

Comment: I am sorry I should have searched the wiki first. Thank you

Comment: Either the wiki or the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/) are good places to search when you're dealing with a sequence of integers.

Comment: $$st_n=\frac{\left(3+2 \sqrt{2}\right)^n-\left(3-2 \sqrt{2}\right)^n}{4 \sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: See [MSE question 76040](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76040/general-formula-to-obtain-triangular-square-numbers) with several answers to your question.